# programmatically hooked-up event not firing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I'm creating a table containing a couple of buttons. These buttons hookup to events firing a method for updating a specific database item. For somekind of reason the event isn't proper hooked-up. The method that should be executed isn't executed at all. What am I doing wrong

pseudo code:

```
public void createTable(List<BLL> itemlist)
{ 
  //newtable;

  foreach (BLL item in itemlist)
  {
  //newrow; 
  //create multiple cells...

   TableCell cell = new TableCell();
   Button button = new Button();
   button.ID = "buttonname" + counter.ToString();
   button.Text = "Update";
   button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.UpdateButton_Click);
   cell.Controls.Add(button);

  //addCellToTableRow
  }
  //addRowToTable
}

public void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //logic to get sender and update database.
   //debugger doesn't get to the breakpoint here.
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the createTable method in your page_load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read up on the [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

When you create dynamic controls, you need to recreate them on every post back as well - this is best done in the `OnInit` event handler.

If you do not do so, the objects and any attached events do not exist, so events will not fire on them.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I know something about the page life cycle but wasn't thinking about it while creating dynamic controls. I will never forget it again!